# ContextMenu and Lambda - is it possible?

Tags: c#, menu, lambda, contextmenu

I'd like to use a context menu and get the user's choice in a local variable.

I tried to use a simple lambda like this:

```
void showMenu(Point pos)
{
    ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();

    int choice = -1;
    var menueChoices = new string[] {"Stretch Mode", "Brightness",  "Saturation", 
                                     "Hues", "Flip Color Stops", "Invert Colors" };
    for (int i = 0; i < menueChoices.Length; i++ )
    {
        MenuItem mi = new MenuItem(menueChoices[i]);
        mi.Index = i;
        mi.Click += (sender, e) =>  { choice = mi.Index; };
        m.MenuItems.Add(i, mi);
    }

    m.Show(flowLayoutPanel1, pos);
    // work with the choice..

}
```

The choice is assigned alright in the lambda (I can print it to the Console) but is reset afterwards.

I have found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224190/lambda-assigning-local-variables) that according to the C# Language Specification:

> **5.3.3.29 Anonymous functions**
>
> For a lambda-expression or anonymous-method-expression expr with a
>   body (either block or expression) body:
>
> - The definite assignment state of an outer variable v before body is the same as the state of v before expr. That is, definite assignment
>     state of outer variables is inherited from the context of the
>     anonymous function.
> - The definite assignment state of an outer variable v after expr is the same as the state of v before expr

OK. Now, I realize that I could create a non-anonymous function but I'd really love to use this concise syntax for a job as trivial as assigning one integer. I guess I missed something obvious? About Lambdas? Or about ContextMenus??

I tried a Property and also changing the MenueItem but didn't find **how persist anything** from that lambda..

**Update:**

Now that I have learned the `menu.Show` doesn't block as a `ShowDialog` does, I can change my code simply to

```
mi.Click += (sender, e) =>  {  menuAction( mi) ;  };
```

and

```
void menuAction(MenuItem choice)
{
    //..do my stuff
}
```

So the Property change I had tried as well **was persisted** after all but I had used the Property too soon and read the 'outer variable' part of the specs a bit too pessimistically..

Comment: `choice` is only assigned, But where it is used?

Comment: I'll use it when it gets a value.. I didn't include the testing stuff; just imagine a few `Console.WriteLine("Choice: " + choice);`

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You are storing the user's choice in a local that will be out of scope when the user chooses. What is the point of this? If you are defining the event handler "in place" with a lambda, why do you need to store anything to begin with (unless its state change in your current class in which case you should be using an instance field, not a local)?

Comment: What's it to you? But since you are asking the obvious: I'll call a few functions depending on the choice made or set a certain mode. And no, instance fields or properties don't work either, as stated in my post and also in the Language Specification. Yes I could inline at least those calls, too, but that seems rather clumsy, given that they'll need some setting up..

Comment: What is it to me? Nice attitude towards someone who's trying to help. Ill spell it out for you one more time because evidently it's not obvious to you. You are assigning to a local that is out of scope when the event handler is invoked. `m.Show` does not block until an option is selected by the user. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry for my rude reply. I do appreciate your efforts but I really don't understand how you can miss my point and I hate it when pepole try to persudade me that my goal is off. Well, I love to put my foot im my mouth, when they show me that I am, but here I don't think I am. I have added a tiny comment to illustrate, what I really think is obvious..  Sorry again, no offence meant!

Comment: @InBetween: Finally: the locality was beside the point, as I had tried a property, too. But the __non-blocking__ part is what tripped me! Sorry again for my flippancy (if that's a word..)

Comment: I'm not missing your point. I've been telling you that `Show` does not block since the beginning...that is why `choice` is out of scope when the  handler is run and why your code didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that calling `Show` on your `ContextMenu` will block until the menu is closed.

This is in fact **not** the case, the `showMenu` method will exit right after showing the menu, before the user selects an item, and your `choice` local will be thin air at that point.

You must use an instance or otherwise referenced variable to store the selection in.

Typically, you would define a field on the class which contains `showMenu`, and reference that field in your lambda.

However, that field will be populated only when the user selects an item, which is **not** right after you call `Show` on the `ContextMenu`.

Comment: Ahh, that's it! Yes I thought `Show` blocks. Looking at my foot ;-)